# Migrate Azure website to local PC VIsual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Nopcommerce CMS website via Azure websites gallery. Now I need to migrate the .sln file and databases to my PC to give the whole package for a friend. How to do this.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. You could just connect to your web site using an FTP Client (ie:
   FileZilla) and just pull the files down that way, or
2. Use Site Control Management ("Kudu") to download a .zip of your web site.

I prefer #2. It's fast and easy.

Here are the steps for #2:

1). Navigate to your website using your browser.

2). Replace the URL in the browser to reference the Kudu companion site for your web site.  For example, if your site is contoso.azurewebsites.net, change the URL to contoso.***scm***.azurewebsites.net.
If prompted to authenticate, sign-in using your Azure Subscription credentials.

3). From the Kudu menu, select the **Debug Console -> CMD** option.

[image]

4). Click the download link for the site folder.  This will package the site up into a .zip file and start the download.

[image]

5). Extract the .zip on your local hard drive and you're on your way.

Comment: Can I get Database file from this method #2. After I download the .zip file from Kudu, can I distribute the file to my friends to use it?

Comment: This is just for the site content.  Your database, possibly SQL Database or a VM running your DB of choice, could be scripted to easily recreate it.

Comment: What I need is a simple solution to make a Package with site content and Database of the site. Are there any?

Comment: It will depend on your site.  Some of those websites have setup/initialization scripts for the database.  For example, Orchard does.  Not sure which one you're using.  Others may require you to connect to the database and generate a setup script.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me in someway but not exactly not what I want.